# Finding the index of object in array rather than object itself

Tags: kotlin

I have an array of objects (object called Image) and I would like to find the index of an object in the array that fits a certain criteria. Instead, my current code returns the object itself and not its index in the array:

```
val originalImage = imagesArray.find {it.position == 2}
```

My Image class:

```
data class Image (
    val position: Int? = 0,
    val coor: IntArray = intArrayOf(0, 0)
) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return super.equals(other)
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return super.hashCode()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find in the array an image object that its position is equal to 2 and get back its index.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html

Comment: Oh you're right thank you very much